# Saving data in Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

If I have created say a neural net in pine script and trained it what methods are available so that I can save the weights from the net and reuse them in an application? I can fin no save method. IS there any way to transfer data generated during the run of one indicator or function and hen save it for later use by another indicator or function?

I've searched but can find no save method

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such functionality in `pinescript`.